# librdkafka C API Kafka Consumer doesn't read all messages correctly

Tags: c, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, confluent-platform

I am using `librdkafka` C API consumer (specifically using `rd_kafka_consumer_poll` to read and I did call `rd_kafka_poll_set_consumer` before this)

Problem I see is that in my google test I do following

1. write 3 messages to kafka
2. init/start kafka consumer (`rd_kafka_consumer_poll`)
3. in `rebalance_cb` I set each partition offset to `RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_STORED` and assign them to handle
4. At this point I believe it should read 3 messages but it reads only last message but surprisingly offset for each partition is already updated!

Am I missing something here using Kafka consumer?

And one more question is I initially thought stored offset is in kafka broker and   there is unique offset for topic + consumer group id + partition combination.

So I thought different consumer groups reading same topic should have different offset.

However, it doesn't look like the case. I am always reading from same offset when  used different consumer groups.

I am suspecting this may be related to offset commit but not sure where to tackle this.

Any insight?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configuration to look at : `auto.offset.reset`

From [Kakfa consumer documentation](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs) :

> What to do when there is no initial offset in Kafka or if the current
>   offset does not exist any more on the server

From [librdkafka documentation](https://github.com/edenhill/librdkafka/blob/master/CONFIGURATION.md) :

> Action to take when there is no initial offset in offset store or the
>   desired offset is out of range: 'smallest','earliest' - automatically
>   reset the offset to the smallest offset, 'largest','latest' -
>   automatically reset the offset to the largest offset, 'error' -
>   trigger an error which is retrieved by consuming messages and checking
>   'message->err'.  Type: enum value

Default value is **latest**.

Furthermore,

```
#define RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_STORED -1000
```

So, you're trying to set partition offset to -1000 which is obviously not a valid offset.
Apparently, librdkafka reads last message in this case (I didn't check code).

Comment: You're answer is spot on. Thank you! About your comment about setting partition offset: If no offset value given it will default RD_KAFKA_OFFSET_STORED. If there is an offset stored in the broker the offset will be set based on the stored offset, otherwise the offset will be set based on "auto.offset.reset". The conclusion is that for most scenarios there is no need to explicitly set the offset for a "topic-partition".